# Redirect loop installing laravel 4 in subdirectory/subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

Hi i've installed laravel 4 inside a subfolder on my main domain.

```
domain.com/laravel4/
```

Inside laravel 4 ive created an .htaccess that points to the public folder of laravel.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess inside the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem is I got a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

**htaccess inside the public folder**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteBase /public/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```